# How to set HTML lang attribute for different country?

Tags: php, html

I have 4 *WordPress* pages for 4 countries.

I want to use different HTML language attitude code for each page by one header.php

```
<html lang="en">
<html lang="pt">
<html lang="id">
<html lang="vi">
```

I tried with this code, but it's not working.

```
<?php 
if($page == 'https://www.exmaple.com/pt') {
    $language = 'pt';
    }
elseif($page == 'https://www.exmaple.com/es') {
    $language = 'es';
    }
elseif($page == 'https://www.exmaple.com/id') {
    $language = 'id';
    }
elseif($page == 'https://www.exmaple.com/vi') {
    $language = 'vi';
    }
 else {
    $language = 'en';
    }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $language; ?>">
```

Comment: what is the problem, it's working fine

Comment: Describe your problem/error in the question.

Comment: all page result showing - <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

Comment: Hi Ayaan please once check this http://tech-blog.borychowski.com/index.php/2009/03/htaccess/redirect-according-to-browser-language-mod-rewrite-and-http_accept_language/

Comment: @JustIn I don't want redirect. I using hreflang tag. Just want to put html lang attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $page try using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

It should give current URL being used.

Answer (score 0):

In code small syntax error

```
<html lang="<?php echo $language; ?>">
```

else use

```
<html lang="<?= $language; ?>">
```

Comment: all page result showing only portuguese language <html lang="pt">

Comment: @Ayaan what is the value of `$page` variable?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny I don't know what you want.
I'm not an expert with PHP. what is $page variable?

Comment: @Ayaan you don't need to be expert on PHP, when you use `if($page == 'https://www.exmaple.com/pt')` then you should know what's the value of `$page` here :)

Comment: How can I set $page variable? 

Comment: Try debugging with ``print_r($variable);`` to see what you get from your variable.